# Android GCM Java Server - Push Notification without message data

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop java server to send push notification in my app.

I succeed to send a notification but I have two problems ...

1. The message text not appear in status bar (only the name of the application is displayed)
2. When i click on the notification in the status bar nothing happens (not opening the application)

This is my code of the java server:

```
    //ArrayList<String> userGcmList = new ArrayList<String>();   
    ArrayList<String> userRegIdGcmList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    //my phone
    userRegIdGcmList.add("***********");        

    int numverOfDevicesRegisterd = userRegIdGcmList.size(); 

    try {                   
        //AI KEY 
        Sender sender = new Sender("*****************");    

        // use this line to send message with payload data
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("1")
            .timeToLive(3)
            .delayWhileIdle(true)
            .addData("message", "Text in the status bar does not appear")
            .build();

        // Use this for multicast messages
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, userRegIdGcmList, numverOfDevicesRegisterd);
        sender.send(message, userRegIdGcmList, numverOfDevicesRegisterd);           
        System.out.println(result.toString());  

        if (result.getResults() != null) {
            int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
            if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
            }
        } else {
            int error = result.getFailure();
            System.out.println(error);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I open the port 5228 on my router but it does not change...

and the source in my app :

> ```
> /**
>  * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
>  */
> private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
> ```

```
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, when);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);   
}
```

Comment: @ Mica, I need to implement the same. Could you please help me to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ class name:GCMIntentService

Comment: Thanks, I succeed to display properly message, but I do still unable to launch the application.

In logcat i have : I/ActivityManager(326): START {flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.****.****/android.app.LauncherActivity bnds=[0,158][720,286]} from pid -1